# "Телесно()ориентированная психотерапия"

Tags: орфография

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно писать "телесно()ориентированная": слитно или в два слова? Это, вроде как, единое понятие и произносится слитно, поэтому хочется написать тоже слитно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ПРАВИЛЬНО: телесно-ориентированная педагогика, хотя в Интернете можно встретить все три формы написания.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

С одной стороны, слово в наибольшей степени подходит под вариант «наречие + прилагательное»: телесно ориентированный (то есть ориентированный на телесный контакт), сравнить: промышленно развитый, общественно полезный.

С другой стороны, это не словосочетание, а ТЕРМИН, который должен являться самостоятельным СЛОВОМ с дефисным или слитным написанием. Слитное написание для опорного слова ориентированный неудобно (оно слишком длинное), поэтому термины этого вида стали писаться через дефис, например: личностно-ориентированная педагогика, социально-ориентированный маркетинг.

Таким образом, можно считать, что эти термины  имеют особую форму написания.